# routing calls from landline to end user cell phones

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, voip, server-room, pstn

I have to setup  a server to route telephone calls coming to a particular landline no to cell phone phones depending upon the availability of user.

I want to  know what technology call centres or telecom giants use for the same.
While exploring some such options I came across
following

1) http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/yate-is-free-voip-client-for-linux-that-supports-gtalk/
2) http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/meta-ul-pbx-server

Let me know if these are what will serve my purpose.
Also let me know what hardware I might need along with setting up of such servers.
What keywords should I exactly Google.We use Ubuntu servers in our environment.

Answer (score 0):

If the routing/relationship is across multiple/different carriers, then "availability" is usually not possible and the only options are typically along:

- Simultaneous ringing
- Sequential ringing/forwarding (follow-me)

Comment: so do let me know how,what keywords should I google.Any advice of yours will have value to me.

Comment: How about - "Simultaneous ringing", "Sequential ringing", "Sequential forwarding"...

Comment: I am able to follow your tips also let me know if there are 10 different mobile phones and I Want to outgoing call to appear as if it came from same number (office kind of ) then what keyword I should search or what technology will help me.

Comment: Not sure what you asking, but Caller-ID information will usually not forward across systems.

Answer (score 0):

u need google for
  voip DID, sip provider, callerid

for large setups better use something like kamailio.org. to setup it u need hi-level voip administrator

for low load use asterisk (software pbx). i higly not recomend u use YATE.

if u want CALLERID changable, u need ask ur sip/did provider about posibility to show CID on mobile calls.